# Javascript ES6: setting <h1> with local storage and form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the element `#welcome_banner` by using a function in javascript that takes a form submission and sets it to `localStorage` and then pulls that info and sets it onto an `<h1>` tag.  Apparently it works but only changes the tag for a millisecond and then it disappears!  I have tried doing the `.innerHTML` setting in various places inside and outside of the `function clickHandler()` and in the main body of the script.  I am certain this is something superbasic I am missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<script >
//set display name to form submission, set welcome banner to display name
function clickHandler () {
    document.querySelector('#display_name').onsubmit = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('dn', dn);
        document.querySelector('#welcome_banner').innerHTML=changeWelcomeBanner;
    }
};


function changeWelcomeBanner () {
    var dn = localStorage.getItem('#dn').value;
    var welcomeBanner = document.getElementById('#welcome_banner');
    welcomBanner.innerHTML = `Hello ${dn}`;
}
</script>

<title>Project 2</title>


    <body style="background-color:#ff3300;">
    <h1 id="welcome_banner"></h1>

    <form id="display_name">
        <input id="dn" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="" type="text">
        <button>set display name</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to do this are as follows:

1. Store the typed text in localStorage, you're doing this in the event handler for the form submission: `localStorage.setItem('dn', dn);`
2. When you submit the form, the page is going to refresh from the server. This is why you're only seeing the text briefly, then the page reloads from the server with no knowledge of what was there before.
3. Look for information about page events and write a handler for the DOMContentLoaded event like you did for your submit event handler.  DOMContentLoaded is well supported these days. Something like: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   // code to check local storage goes here...
   });`
4. In that handler you want to check localStorage like you're doing here: `var dn = localStorage.getItem('dn').value;` and if there is a value there, set the innerHtml of the `<h1>` to that value, like you're doing here: `welcomBanner.innerHTML = 'Hello ${dn}';`

I think you might have had a stray # character in your localStorage.getItem call that I removed in the steps above. You might also want to have default text you post if there's nothing found in localStorage when you check.

Comment: Thanks!  As Sean Connery said in 'Finding Forester': "You're the Man now Dog!"

Comment: The localstorage did work as it's supposed to do.  However in the larger view of the project I'm working on I decided to do the registration / username login part of this project using flask_sessions, which has more functionality that I know how to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example:
If you are calling a function to get the value from Local Storage, be sure you have a `return`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="welcome"></h1>
    <input type="text" id="something">
    <button type="button" id="click">CLICK ME</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var x=document.getElementById("something").value;
            
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=x;
            
            localStorage.setItem('x', JSON.stringify(x));
            
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = getData();
     });

            function getData(){
                var retrieve=localStorage.getItem('x');
                return JSON.parse(retrieve); //Now return the value
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```